# Why Would The SiteMapPath In SharePoint, Not Display All Sub Sites?

Tags: sharepoint, sitemappath

I have a SharePoint with site A, which also has a nested site B, and inside of that, site C and inside of that site D.

On the home page for site D, my URL is perfect.  It shows http://A/B/C/D/Pages/default.aspx
But my breadcrumb shows me A > C > D

Can anyone give me one reason why this would occur in SharePoint 2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user may not have permissions on site B. Navigation is security trimmed.